# How can I preview different view controllers of a storyboard in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode

XCode has an excellent feature where you can preview your storyboards on various devices. This is a great way to test layouts on multiple different iOS devices without having to run them all individually in the simulator.

Is it possible to preview each individual view controller of a storyboard? XCode defaults to the root view controller of the storyboard, which in my case usually contains little or no UI elements and is therefore useless. I want to preview child view controllers of my storyboards. Is this possible?

[image: XCode preview feature]

Comment: Preview shows the layout of current view controller selected not the root controller always when i do it.

Comment: You are correct! I knew it must be possible. Make that an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview shows the layout of current view controller selected not the root controller always when i do it.